# Can't upload to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am getting an issue uploading to shinyapps.io. I had issues with the firewall before so I am wondering if maybe there are leftover issues there but I can't find anything that would indicate that in the error message.

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 4222252...Error in force(code) : Could not upload file.
Calls: <Anonymous> -> withStatus -> force
Execution halted
```

The application is a very simple shinyapp that I used to test. There's really only a dummy data.table and a linechart created with the billboarder package. Nothing crazy going on there.

I tried to log it and this is what I got:

```
* Connection 2 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 2
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with api.shinyapps.io port 443
* Connection 3 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 3
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with api.shinyapps.io port 443
* Found bundle for host api.shinyapps.io: 0x1fd5bd908e0 [can pipeline]
*   Trying 18.204.73.112...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.shinyapps.io (18.204.73.112) port 443 (#5)
> GET /v1/applications/?filter=account_id:932539&count=100&offset=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.shinyapps.io
User-Agent: rsconnect/0.8.17
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Date: Thu, 03 Jun 2021 08:06:19 GMT
X-Auth-Token: EB5EF5C5A9A0A1AD8021108F4973EA4F
X-Auth-Signature: NDA5YzIwY2E3YTMxMTQ1Y2U4YzYwZjdhMTA2ODM2NzJmOWE1MDExNTI3NmFiODRmNzFkMjUzZmJlZDA3YWRkZg==; version=1
X-Content-Checksum: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 03 Jun 2021 08:06:20 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 5879
< Connection: keep-alive
< Etag: "36941c41b5fad4ebdec0fb9ed5ef1154e9a52e79"
< Server: TornadoServer/4.5.3
< 
* Connection #5 to host api.shinyapps.io left intact
* Found bundle for host api.shinyapps.io: 0x1fd5bd908e0 [can pipeline]
* Hostname api.shinyapps.io was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 18.204.73.112...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.shinyapps.io (18.204.73.112) port 443 (#6)
> GET /v1/applications/?filter=account_id:932539&count=100&offset=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.shinyapps.io
User-Agent: rsconnect/0.8.17
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Date: Thu, 03 Jun 2021 08:06:31 GMT
X-Auth-Token: EB5EF5C5A9A0A1AD8021108F4973EA4F
X-Auth-Signature: MjdiYWUzZWYzODIzNmM5NzMxMGZhOGM5MTQ4Y2VjMTFlYjdlODFkMWRhNDU4ZGFkNjNmMGQ5YmVlMTllZGQ5Ng==; version=1
X-Content-Checksum: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 03 Jun 2021 08:06:32 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 5879
< Connection: keep-alive
< Etag: "36941c41b5fad4ebdec0fb9ed5ef1154e9a52e79"
< Server: TornadoServer/4.5.3
< 
* Connection #6 to host api.shinyapps.io left intact
* Connection 4 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 4
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with api.shinyapps.io port 443
* Found bundle for host api.shinyapps.io: 0x1fd5bd908e0 [can pipeline]
*   Trying 3.231.196.102...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.shinyapps.io (3.231.196.102) port 443 (#7)
> GET /v1/applications/?filter=account_id:932539&count=100&offset=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.shinyapps.io
User-Agent: rsconnect/0.8.17
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Date: Thu, 03 Jun 2021 08:07:34 GMT
X-Auth-Token: EB5EF5C5A9A0A1AD8021108F4973EA4F
X-Auth-Signature: YjMzMzNlMDQ0MTEwZmZmYjQxOTMxMzA1N2JkMzc4ZmM0MTA5ZGE4ZmE5NGFmYmY5MGE0ZWZmNjAzOTFmZjc5Yg==; version=1
X-Content-Checksum: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

* schannel: failed to decrypt data, need more data
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 03 Jun 2021 08:07:36 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 5879
< Connection: keep-alive
< Etag: "36941c41b5fad4ebdec0fb9ed5ef1154e9a52e79"
< Server: TornadoServer/4.5.3
< 
* Connection #7 to host api.shinyapps.io left intact
* Found bundle for host api.shinyapps.io: 0x1fd5bd908e0 [can pipeline]
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying 3.231.196.102...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.shinyapps.io (3.231.196.102) port 443 (#8)
> GET /v1/applications/?filter=account_id:932539&count=100&offset=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.shinyapps.io
User-Agent: rsconnect/0.8.17
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Date: Thu, 03 Jun 2021 08:09:51 GMT
X-Auth-Token: EB5EF5C5A9A0A1AD8021108F4973EA4F
X-Auth-Signature: MDhlNzE0MDFhMmJhNjU3NTA2Y2UyOTk3ZWY2OWQ1ZDgyNjMyMWRhYjcyOTNhOTMyMDFkMGY4YzIwZmJiZWM1MQ==; version=1
X-Content-Checksum: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 03 Jun 2021 08:09:51 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 5879
< Connection: keep-alive
< Etag: "36941c41b5fad4ebdec0fb9ed5ef1154e9a
GET /v1/applications/?filter=account_id:932539&count=100&offset=0 870ms
```

If anyone has any idea what's happening here I would love to hear it!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55211794/cant-deploy-large-ish-rds-files-to-shinyapp-io-in-rstudio

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is nothing in my directory other than my app.R and the standard R files (workspace, project, etc)